# Convert to seconds from the give date format

Tags: java

i have written the code for getting date-format from the seconds which is giving the correct result .But when i try to get the seconds from the date-format i am getting the wrong result. Here is the code

```
public class DateTimeFind
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String seconds = "1325376000";
        DateTimeFind dtf = new DateTimeFind();
        // Displaying correct date from the given seconds
        dtf.displayDate(seconds);
        String date = "Sunday, January 1, 2012 12:00,AM";
        // Displaying wrong value of seconds from the given date.
        dtf.displaySeconds(date);
    }

    private void displayDate(String seconds){
        long startEndSec = Long.parseLong(seconds);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm,a", Locale.getDefault());
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(startEndSec * 1000L));
        System.out.println(dateString);

    }

    private void displaySeconds(String startEndDateTime){
        SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm,a");
        long c = 0;
        long c1 = 0;
        try
        {
            Date t = (Date) sourceFormat.parse(startEndDateTime);
            c = t.getTime() / 1000;
        }
        catch(ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        System.out.println(Long.toString(c));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the same `TimeZone` on the `SimpleDateFormat` used in `displaySeconds()` method. Add the following line:

```
sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using `Locale.getDefault()` to treat date formats in the English is also not entirely right. Use `Locale.ENGLISH` instead and add it to the constructor of the `SimpleDateFormat` as used in the `displaySeconds()` method as well.